# SIGABRT: Object reference not set to an instance of an object SetStatusBarColor Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

I get the crash `SIGABRT: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when submitting the App to the AppStore. I checked the log file from Apple. Noticed at this point:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    var statusbar = DependencyService.Get<IStatusBarPlatformSpecific>();
    statusbar.SetStatusBarColor(Color.FromHex("f1f1f1"));
}
```

**IStatusBarPlatformSpecific.cs**

```
public interface IStatusBarPlatformSpecific
{
    void SetStatusBarColor(Color color);
}
```

Most affected OS: 15.4.1

[image]

Looking forward to a solution from everyone. Thank you

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here . Especially, the `SetStatusBarColor` method.

Comment: I updated here: https://github.com/chimditruvn/Appssss. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the `statusbar` like below:

```
    UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame);
           

            if(statusBar == null)
            {
                //throw a meaningful exception or give some useful feedback!
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                statusBar.BackgroundColor = color.AddLuminosity(0).ToUIColor();
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);
            }
```

Comment: I will try it and give you feedback here

Comment: I submitted the App to the AppStore and Apple responded with the same error. However, this time it says Most affected OS 15.5

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: I think you should know what the cause the null reference firstly and then fix it.I have updated my code,hope that helps.

Comment: I understand what you say. It's not null. I tried on emulator and real device. However, when I submit it to the AppStore, I get the same error response as above. It's hard to understand

Comment: I think it's a potential issue in AppStore as it only happens when deploying to AppStore.

Comment: Most likely, it just happens when I submit to the AppStore and get a response from Apple. Do you have any suggestions for how I can respond to AppStore reviews?